# youtube-dl apache/php issue

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, youtube, youtube-dl

I installed the lastest version of youtube-dl and it works perfectly via the terminal but not via the web.

Terminal: (Works perfectly. Downloads the video.)

```
[****@****** bin]# /opt/ActivePython-2.7/bin/python /usr/bin/youtube-dl-test -g http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3rzmQqVszo
```

And it works with php via the terminal: (Works. Downloads video)

```
[****@****** ****]# php test.php
```

But it fails when I visit it via the web. http://sifdsfdfdf.com/test.php

PHP script: (Fails. Blank page.)

```
$url=exec("/opt/ActivePython-2.7/bin/python /usr/bin/youtube-dl-test -g http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3rzmQqVszo");
echo $url;
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl-test/__main__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl-test/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl-test/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 549, in <module>
    CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
MemoryError
```

Thanks

Comment: My first impression is that this looks like a bug in ActiveState's python. If you write just `import ctypes` into a file and execute it in php, do you get the same error? Does the error persist if you're using plain cpython?

Comment: I got it working! Woohoo! 3 days of stress and a new gray hair. I just upgraded to python3.3 and it worked like a charm via the terminal and by php. :)